# VECM in R: how to add differenced lags?

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

Good afternoon!

I want to estimate VECM in R and I have 2 questions:

For instance, I want to estimate a model (in vector form):
$$
\bigtriangleup y_t = \pi_1 y_{t-1} + \pi_2 y_{t-2} + A_1 \bigtriangleup y_{t-1} + A_2 \bigtriangleup y_{t-2} + A_3 \bigtriangleup y_{t-3} + \varepsilon_t
$$
How can I specify in `R` exact number of lags for cointegrating relationship (2 lags in the example) and exact number of lags for differenced variables (3 lags here)?

**Update**.

- The proof that only one lag in cointegrating relationship is sufficient: [Proof](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/12/some-interesting-issues-in-vecm-using-r/)
- `R` packages provide opportunity to add any number of lags for differenced variables in the system. For instance, `ca.jo` from `vars` has argument `K`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two distinct questions in your post. I suggest splitting it into two posts. I will answer the first one here.

1. Having more than one lag of the error correction term is an unusual representation of a VECM. You can express this by an equivalent representation that contains a single lag of the error correction term. Do that, and you will not have to worry about coding it up in R. (Also, you have forgotten to include the error term at the end of the equation for $\Delta y_t$.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will split the second question into another post. I understood the rationale for setting 1 lag for error correction terms, but how can I set the number of lags for **differenced** variables (3 lags in the example)?

Comment: @rsx, what functions from what package are you using to specify and estimate the model? Usually their descriptions would contain the answer to your query.

Comment: Sorry, I've been very busy this month. And I would like to ask you how can I add some useful links with answers for my question (if anyone else will come across the same question in future, he/she will be able to find detailed clarification via the links I want to provide)? By the way, one more question. When I try to mention you with @Richard Hardy in the first line of this comment, this mentioning strangely disappears and inside the text such tag seems not to work as you see...

Comment: @rsx, you can edit your question, that way you can include links. When you write at-username under a question or answer posted by a user called username and there are no other users that have posted comments there, the at-username gets deleted. The user called username gets notified anyway, so there is no need.